# Breeze WebAPI Entity Framework Self Tracking entity not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am in a process of developing an N-Tier solution for which I am using Entity Framework (4.X) DB first approach with ADO.Net Self Tracking entity in Repository layer. I have MVC WebAPI project and Breeze configured there. I have breeze client also configured in a seperate MVC UI project. The communication between Breeze client and server seems to work fine except that there are no Entity Ness like entityAspect object on client side after the query executes and resuls are returned.

When I change from ADO.net Self tracking entity to normal ADO.Net entity, everything seems to work fine i.e., entityAspect gets created correctly. So, just want to know if there is support in Breeze for the Self Tracking entities or not?

My Dev configs. are VS 2010 & MVC 4. I know these are bit old but client does not have license for the newer versions at the moment.

Comment: I believe Microsoft itself dropped support for Self Tracked entities.